# Mode responsible for phenomena in disk resonator

Tags: resonator

As you can see below there is resonance because the transmission line is the circumference of the ring.
in the solution they set the phase such that it has integer number of wavelength which is the condition for resistance.
But I don't understand the mode of operation here.
The ring so PEC the ground is PEC, the dielectric walls is PMC.
So I assume we have TEM MODE?
but the \$e^{j*\beta*a*\phi}\$ expression is very crucial in understanding.
Does \$e^{j*\beta*a*\phi}\$ comes from the E-field? There is no such expression in TEM mode.
what is the source of the \$e^{j*\beta*a*\phi}\$ came from? Is it E-field, H-field, or is it the pointing vector.
Saying that its the wave is not very much specific because it doesn't allow me to recognize what mode we operate on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think in the second sentence, you mean "resonance"; not "resistance", right?

Answer (score 0):

The mode in which the wave propagates along the ring is irrelevant, and hence not specified. Depending on the actual dimensioning of the dielectric, the width of the conductive strip, and a ground plane, there might be more than one mode that can propagate. (There's really no reason this needs to be a stripline/microstrip; it could just as well just be a ring made out of coaxial cable, or a rectangular-crosssection wave guide: the important principle is "it's a ring".)

The only thing that matters is that the phase length of the ring is a multiple of a full wavelength, because by definition, no matter which modes are present, the field "picture" repeats every full wavelength.